# New car battery (12V) internal short circuit

Tags: batteries, short-circuit

For a new car 12V battery (electrolyte full) without any accessories/cable connected, no charging/discharging,  what will happen when there is an internal short circuit (one of the internal positive and negative plate accidentally touches each other)?

Will one of the following scenarios happen:

1. Battery explodes?
2. Self discharge and temperature rises to a point where it catches fire?

Comment: My thought would be self discharge and temperature rises to where it catches fire.

Comment: Explosions for LA batteries are very rare, but you can find documented examples of it. Heating and venting without explosion is far more common in case of a failure. Do you have any mission critical application?

Comment: I have had used Lead-Acid batteries develop shorted cells - no fire, explosion, or obvious damage to the battery - just couldn't charge it to full voltage. The other cells needed lots of water, but the bad cell didn't loose any water.

Answer (score 2):

Lead-acid batteries aren’t prone to catching fire because neither the plates nor the electrolyte are combustible.  The short-circuit current is rather high, maybe 1000A which corresponds to a couple of kilowatts for one cell.  If the electrolyte boils, which might well happen after a couple of minutes, then it will vent steam, or if it’s sealed it may burst a cell.  It’s most unlikely that more than one cell would short though, as they are physically separated.  It’s more likely that the material at the point of the short circuit would become very hot and melt amtge battery’s enclosure.